# Looking for libraries for scrolling events on Angular 6 like Scrollwizardry

Tags: angular6

I was wondering how do I achieve the effect on the website http://atintell.com/?

I have been trying to use gsap and scrollWizardry but there is always an error about not finding a method because it can't find a class. I've been searching for Jquery plugins but can't find that muck help.

Any recomendation?  what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem. I know two ways to detect the scrollbar position.

1. Use @HostListener(Do not forget to import it) Like bellow.

@HostListener("window:scroll", [$event])

```
onWindowScroll(){
let position = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

if(position==300){
//your code
}
else if(position==500){
//other code
}
}
```

2. You can use jquery to detect the hight of the scrollbar, first, you need to install jquery via. Follow bellow steps.
   a. npm install jquery --save

b. Add script to your index.htlm

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

c. import the jquery in your component like bellow.

```
Import import $ from "jquery";
```

d.Include the following code in the component

```
 function searchShow(){
        try{
          if($(window).scrollTop()>=$('.testimonials').offset().top-215){
            //top means max height of page.
            // Write your code here
          }
          else{
           // Other code here
         }
      } catch(err) {}
      }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: I see, i'll be experimenting with your answer. so I assume that you listen to the scrolling position and you start to activate animations. How would I pin something and how would I set a tween?

Examples:
if(positionIWant) {
   addCssClass(positionFixed)
}

if(anotherPosition){
  anotherELementTransitionX(params)
}